# Do the columns of the matrix span $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 7 \\ 2 & 0 & 3 & 12 \\ 3 & 0 & 4 & 17 \\ 4 & 0 & 5 & 22 \\ 5 & 0 & 1 & 17\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathrm{rref}(A) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Do the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^5$?

My answer is $\mathrm{rref}(A)$ doesn't have a pivot in every row, therefore the columns of $A$ don't span $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Is my answer right and sufficient enough? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You only have four columns in total, and only three are non-zero. Any spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^5$ has at least $5$ elements. Therefore your columns cannot possibly span $\mathbb{R}^5$. There is no need to even consider the RREF of the matrix.

Comment: But.... is my answer correct and sufficient enough?

Comment: @FomoLoco It really depends on what you can take for granted. I can turn around and ask "Why does not having a pivot in every row mean that the columns cannot span $\mathbb{R}^5$?" How would you answer that?